# Using scrum for developing new updates for a released software

Tags: scrum

Hy Guys

The last few days I've been reading some articles and blogs about scrum. But I'm not quite sure if scrum would fit for our process.

In our company we have our own developers for our sofware wich is used by engineers (about 100 engineers). Our developers are continnous implementing new features and improving the Software. So we are cyclical providing a new Version of the Software. The engineers are using the Software for the configuration of PLC's.

Does it make sens to use scrum for such a Project and I don't mean the daily-scrum. Does it make sens to provide / distribute every 4-6 weeks a new increment / Version of the Software. It also would mean, that the documentation for the new version and the distribution is need to be done.

What is your opinion?

Greetings

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (You can also flag for moderator intervention to have this question migrated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though Scrum would be an excellent fit for you.

You get to choose the length of a sprint, though it cannot be longer than 30 days. Throughout the sprint, you work on each product backlog item until it is 'done'. Done means that all work is completed, including any necessary documentation. By the end of the sprint, you should have a 'potentially releasable product increment'.

Whether the product increment is released or not, is decided by the product owner.

Comment: Thank you Derek! Now I only have to convince our management about using scrum ;-) The major business of our company is ro realize scada and automation projects. Thus, the management dosn't understand much about software development.

Answer (score 1):

Scrum is a good framework to manage software development. It permits you to have daily meetings where you can track what people did yesterday, on what are they working on and if there is something blocking or slowing them. This will help also you as a manager or will help your manager to check a burndown chart to see if you are on track for the due date of your planed update version of your software. Definitely is a good agile framework to use.

But first, to start you need to train your team to get use to it, know the company culture, talk with them and see their opinions. You can check Salesforce study case, here is some information: http://www.slideshare.net/sgreene/salesforcecom-agile-transformation-agile-2007-conference probably you can search more information about them because for me, that's the most succesful agile case that I know.

They went from 1 major release in one year, to have multiple releases in one year. I think you could deliver more faster to your engineers and have sooner feedback, also continues integration can help a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your notes. Maybe I missunderstood something in scrum. I thought the working code is released after each sprint, in my case distributed to the engineers. I assume that's not correct? Correct it would be like this: A certain amount of Sprints is defined. After this certain amount of Sprints, there will be a release. After each sprint there is working / releasable code, which is presented to the product owner to check if the requirements from the backlog are fulfilled. The working code after each sprint can be released in some cases. Is this correct?

Comment: At the end of a sprint, you should have a 'potentially releasable product increment'. Whether it gets released or not, is decided by the product owner.

Comment: Reneton, you are right man. The way you release your code is up to you and your product owner. In my experiencie you can deliver the first sprint after you finish the second sprint. But it will depend on how you manage your revision process to make sure everything is already and ready to ship. What Derek is saying also is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scrum of course. but before it you need to find out it's aspects carefully. in you case, you need to shape your team(s) and also define your product owner and scrum master. after that you need to shape product back log and ...
You need to careful about that, as you have 100 engineer that are working with your software, you need to just have 1 product owner for each software or product and he or she will be responsible for product back log and product it self.
Finally may be based on your scenario you need to have short sprints. such as sprints with 1 week length. You need to consider it that, you must not evade the way when you start the way. You may have some difficulties at start, but every thing will go well, if you support it.
I hope you can find a hint for your answer among my words. If not, you can explain it more, so I can explain it more too ;-)